# Missing project sub type error when trying to create a new MonoGame project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, monogame

Hello Im using Visual Studio 2012 and whenver I try to create a new MonoGame content project I get this error...Also if I try to start a windows Mono project or a Android mono project I dont get the same error but whenever i try to compile i get errors, i have unstillaed Mono and xamarin and tried installing and that never solved the issue the only thing left to do is uninstall Visual Studio 2012 but that can take a ton of time so if anyone here can help me it will be appreciated here is the link to the following error.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a workaround for you, although, I still don't fully understand the issue myself and I'd love someone to shed some light on it.

If you open up the project file as plain text you will see a ProjectTypeGuids like so:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{9B831FEF-F496-498F-9FE8-180DA5CB4258};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

If you Google each GUID you will find that one of them is DotNetProjectSubtype id="MonoGame" and the other is Windows (C#).

As far as I can tell you can safely delete the MonoGame one and proceed with your day. I believe it's only used at project creation time.

Comment: the thing is that i cant even start a project it just wont allow me so there is no project file

Comment: According to the following page, the GUID in your screenshot refers to XNA (Windows). What type of project are you trying to create exactly?  http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx Either you are not creating the right type of project or you need to download this http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=23714