# Where to find my GUID on my c# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, guid

Hello I have been having issues with MonoGame when building I get the glbind... error in the opengl32.dll so I was suggested to find my GUID and it sounds like a simple task but i have looked in the project folder files and cant find it I found one which is

```
<ProjectGuid>{325BCA73-8459-49AF-9C31-D4A268BF8A1A}</ProjectGuid>
```

but im looking for one like this

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{9B831FEF-F496-498F-9FE8-180DA5CB4258};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

here is a image of my file folder and the main "collisions".csproj file where I found the one GUID. I have done some research but i cant seem to find an answer as to where to look.
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eonZ7.jpg)

More accuretly im looking for the Projecttypeguids so I can delete one of them to see if that solves my problem as suggested here....I recognized what i worded at the top is kind of vague sorry

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879359/missing-project-sub-type-error-when-trying-to-create-a-new-monogame-project/16908711#comment24440527_16908711)

Comment: The thing is, pretty much anything can have *a* GUID, it's impossible to tell what *the* GUID you're looking for is unless you give us the context - what do you need it for, who suggested you need it and what was their exact phrasing?

Comment: I edited my question sorry it was confusing but i have provided a link to what I was suggested to do..As far as I know I want to locate the <ProjectTypeguids> tag and delete the monegame one and keep the c# one

Comment: Well, were this not Windows, I'd say `grep` for it. (Or use a text editor like Sublime Text that is willing to do a full text search over a directory structure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you linked to shows a project that does not have any type GUIDs listed. If present, the value is mostly used by development tools (e.g. VS uses it to figure out what items to include in the context menus for adding new items.) If there is no project type GUID your project will still "work" for the most part, but you will likely encounter odd behavior in your IDE of choice.

The project type GUID values in your question are correct for a project that is a C# application that uses the MonoGame plugin. If your project file is missing that tag, just add it yourself with whichever GUIDs you want your project to have.

(The list of well-known GUIDs can be found [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx), though the MonoGame one I had to look up on Google.)

Comment: yea I tried adding the specific GUID tag with the c# number and it doesnt work the build and release still fails, and then I tried adding that c# GUID to the project GUID and it fails I dont know what to do.

Comment: do you think that the GUID's have any thing to do with the       Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'.      error?

Comment: no, absolutely not. That error means that you're using the wrong version of `opengl32.dll` that does not have the entry point your trying to use. This is apparently a known bug in MonoGame: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998

Comment: also: you definitely don't want to change the `<ProjectGuid>` tag; that should be a single GUID that is unique to that project. Only the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag can have multiple GUIDs that are reused across projects.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this..Also I was wrong i got confused and mixed up my two errors. Sorry about that but thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first example you gave is the GUID of your project. Hence `ProjectGuid`.
The second is a list of the GUIDs of the project types of your project. Hence `ProjectTypeGuids`.

If you are looking for the GUID of your project, the first example is giving you the correct answer.

Comment: oh yes reading back i acknowledge that my question is sort of vague I was suggested this answer so more accurately im looking for the ProjectTypeGUID  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879359/missing-project-sub-type-error-when-trying-to-create-a-new-monogame-project/16908711#comment24440527_16908711

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't mentioned what you're using winforms or wpf.

OK whatever.The ProjectTypeGuids is not supported in winforms  you can find them if you're  using wpf.

If you're using wpf you can use this code:

```
 public string GetProjectTypeGuids(EnvDTE.Project proj)
       {

      string projectTypeGuids = "";
      object service = null;
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution solution = null;
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy hierarchy = null;
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject aggregatableProject = null;
      int result = 0;

      service = GetService(proj.DTE, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution));
      solution = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution)service;

      result = solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(proj.UniqueName, hierarchy);

      if (result == 0)
      {
         aggregatableProject = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject) hierarchy;
         result = aggregatableProject.GetAggregateProjectTypeGuids(projectTypeGuids);
      }

      return projectTypeGuids;

   }

   public object GetService(object serviceProvider, System.Type type)
   {
      return GetService(serviceProvider, type.GUID);
   }

   public object GetService(object serviceProviderObject, System.Guid guid)
   {

      object service = null;
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
      IntPtr serviceIntPtr;
      int hr = 0;
      Guid SIDGuid;
      Guid IIDGuid;

      SIDGuid = guid;
      IIDGuid = SIDGuid;
      serviceProvider = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)serviceProviderObject;
      hr = serviceProvider.QueryService(SIDGuid, IIDGuid, serviceIntPtr);

      if (hr != 0)
      {
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
      }
      else if (!serviceIntPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
      {
         service = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(serviceIntPtr);
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Release(serviceIntPtr);
      }

      return service;
   }
```

it's from [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007016.aspx)